# What does this equation mean (approx with subscript)?

Tags: notation, relations, equivalence-relations

This might be a silly question, but I have no clue what it means:

[image]

it's from this question i'm working on:

[image]

I'm taking a CS course, and all the math i've done is calculus and linear algebra. I've never see approximation squiggly lines with a subscript. What on earth? I wish schools prepared us more properly, before throwing us the wolves. Half the time I'm spending trying to decipher what any of this means mathematically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you quote defines exactly what $a \approx_f b$ means: $a \approx_f b$ if and only if $f(a) = f(b)$. For example, if we let $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined by $g(x) = x^2$, then $2 \approx_g -2$ because $g(2) = 4 = g(-2)$, but it is not the case that $1 \approx_g 2$, because $g(1) = 1$ and $g(2) = 4$.

Answer (score 6):

The passage you have there *defines* $\approx_f$ to be a certain relation. For any $x$ and $y$, $x \approx_f y$ is either true or false. The passage gives a definition for exactly when it is true.

In other words, it doesn't mean anything in particular outside this passage. This passage defines it.